# require happens out of order

Tags: page-template, variables, include, template-include

I have a page template that is including another file via `require_once`. I want this included file to have access to the `$post` object but it can't find it.

So I ran something like this to see what's happening

**page.php**

```
<?php
    $post_title = $post->post_title;
    echo "Post:<br/>"; var_dump($post_title);

    require_once('inc/external.php');
?>
```

**inc/external.php**

```
<?php
    global $post_title;
    echo "External post:<br/>"; var_dump($post_title, true); echo "<br/><br/>";
?>
```

Not only does `external.php` not see $post_title, but it prints out of order:

**Output:**

```
External post: 
NULL

Post:
Title of the Post
```

Why would the echo/var_dump in the included file run before the original? I feel like this is linked to the fact that the variable can't be read in the included file.

Comment: have you tried `global $post;` inside either PHP file? `external.php` should inherit the variable scope, too, so you can create local variables in `page.php` and have them visible in `external.php`.

Comment: There is a `global $post;` in page.php, just added that to external.php with no effect (note that I'm not actually querying the `$post` variable in external.php).

Answer (score 0):

Must be something with your setup. Following works for me (inside child theme - should work for any theme though):

single.php:

```
global $post;
$bla = $post->post_title;
error_log('post title is: ' . $bla);
include('included.php');
```

included.php:

```
error_log('i am included file: ' . $bla);
```

Output in debug.log:

```
post title is:  Hello test
i am included file: Hello test
```

Both files are inside the same directory.

Comment: Hm. Only difference that I can see is that the included file is in a directory one level down from the parent (edited main post to reflect this). This still shouldn't be messing with the order of output. Going to try with two different pages.

Comment: but does using `include` instead of `require_once` affect the result for you?

Comment: Nope - no difference.